# Matrix determinant with complex coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ a positive integer, define $A=\left(e^{\frac{2i(k-1)(l-1)\pi}{n}}\right)_{1 \leq k,l \leq n} $ , evaluate $\det(A)$.

Comment: it's something like Vandermonde but i don't know how to relate this problem with it . Any ideas ?

Comment: Note: this corresponds to IDFT matrix. Eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) are all known: $n$. Then determinant is equal to $n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the determinant of this Matrix **is a Vandermonde determinant**.

You have : $A = \mathcal{V}(w,w^2,...,w^{n-1})$ where $w=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}}$, and you know the formula for the Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i got it !